# Как типизировать express: = require typesript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

Пытаюсь типизировать конфиг вебпака и не получается типизировать данную строку пишет ошибку, как можно это типизировать? также если есть возможность посмотрите насколько правильно остальные типы типизировала

```
   interface Iexpress {
  static: (id: string) => string;
}
 const express: Iexpress = require("express");
```

сама ошибка

```
 const express: Iexpress = require("express"); 

Это выражение не является вызываемым.
  Тип "Iexpress" не содержит сигнатуры вызова.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 interface Iexpress {
      static: (id: string) => string;
    }
    
    const express: Iexpress = require("express");
    const bodyParser: {
      urlencoded(arg0: { extended: boolean }): string;
      json(): string;
      NodeRequire: (id: string) => string;
    } = require("body-parser");
    
    const path: {
      join: (__dirname: string, id2: any) => string;
      NodeRequire: (id: string) => string;
    } = require("path");
    
    const app = express();
    
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
      console.log("in development.");
    } else {
      console.log("in production.");
    }
    
    /* App Config */
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../dist")));
    
    /* Server Initialization */
    app.get("/", (req: any, res: { sendFile: (arg0: string) => string }) =>
      res.sendFile("index.html")
    );
    var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    app.listen(port, () =>
      console.log(
        `Server initialized on: http://localhost:${port} // ${new Date()}`
      )
    );
```

Comment: это всё не похоже на typescript. тут нет ничего про реакт. тут нет ничего вебпак. удивительно несовпадающий с вопросом набор меток

Comment: зачем вам такая типизация? лучше установите type definitions for Express npmjs.com/package/@types/express

Comment: Добавила скриншот где у меня в проекте используется

Comment: все типы здесь нужно типизировать через types/express?

Comment: попробуйте поставить https://npmjs.com/package/@types/express и https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/body-parser, думаю сами во всём разберётесь

Comment: спасибо, есть пример типизированного сервера? который у меня?

Comment: чем вы рискуете попробовав сами? ну, написал вам ["пример"](https://codesandbox.io/s/node-js-forked-hsx0kk?file=/src/index.js), понаводите курсором на переменные app, req, res и т.п.

Comment: интересно, скриншот прикрепила, там где у вас типы у меня стоит тип any

Comment: @Екатерина, вам же сказали, что нужно поставить, чтобы были типы.

Comment: если расширения файлы app.js, то типы пишутся если app.ts пишет в типах any

Comment: Установите два пакета по ссылке и будут у вас отображаться типы в `ts` файлах.